# Meteor / MongoDB - How to prove whether any item in an array is equal to a specific value and than $pull an item from another array in case 'true'?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, methods, collections

My problem is, that I wrote the following code:

```
Meteor.methods({

    'pushItems': function (itemId) {
    var specificValue = "12";

    if (this.userId) {
      userManagement.update({
        '_id': this.userId
    }, {
        $push: {
          'itemIds': itemId,
          'values': specificValue
                   }
               }
            );
         }
       }
    });
```

After I called this method, one item with an "itemId" is stored within the array "itemIds" and one item is stored with "12" within the array "values". All of this happens in one user object.

Now, I need to write a function which checks whether "12" is within 'values' of the users and in case this is 'true' it should $pull the chronological first added itemId [0] out of the array 'itemIds'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method below will find a document that contains the argument (value) in the `values` array, and will remove the item at [0] from the `itemId` array

```
Meteor.methods({
    'pullItems': function (value) {
        return userManagement.update(
            { values: value }, 
            { $pop: { itemId: -1 }}
        );
    } 
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. The $pop command was what is searched for and solves at least 50 % of my problem. However, the { values: value }, does not work ('unexpected identifier') and the app crashes. Maybe there is a way with an 'if' and a search/find function to solve this? In fact, I just need to declare a variable and say ' if this variable is in 'values', do the $pop job. I am thinking about it, but I am not pro enough to do so :D Additionally, I have a general question (I know it´s a noobish one): What exactly does the "return"? Thanks.

Comment: No prob! I'm not sure why the ```values: value``` isn't working. That should search the ```values``` array of the object for the `value``` passed to the method. Try the ```if``` statement and if you can't manage it comment here and I'll help you. The return statement basically just returns the result of the update call to the client. You don't really need the ```return``` statement but I put it there as habit

Comment: Ah, I know why the values-thing didn´t work. I just forgot to pass it from the Meteor.call. But it doesn´t just find the 'value' in the values-array. It writes a completly new doc into that user and deletes the other ones (I guess it deletes them, because we ommitted a $push or sth.). However, I don´t need to write any new doc into the user, I just need to know whether the value is in there and if this is the case, it should $pop in 'itemIds'. I will write an attempt of an `if`- function and post it to show what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: So, I know that it doesn´t work, but it should clarify my needs: 
Meteor.methods({ 'pullItems': function () 
var value = “Int32”;
{ if (this.userId && userManagement.find({
            "values": {$gt: value} === true})) {
      userManagement.update({
          '_id': this.userId
        }, 

        {
          $pop: {
            'itemId’: -1
          }
        } 
      );
    };
  }
});
.   
I need to find out whether there is any item in the ItemId-Array, which is greater than value. If this is true, do the ‘userManagement.update ({$pop job}).